# Urls exceeding memcached key length limit

Tags: java, url, hash, memcached

I am using memcached to store an encoded url as key and a java object as value. If an encoded url exceeds length of 250 chars (key limit for memcached), I discard it as it is not desirable to truncate a url. But I want to use all the urls I receive, irrespective of their length. So I am thinking to create MD5 hash for url(without encoding) and use that as key and store the original url in Java object in the value part.

However, urls I receive contain all types of chars like spaces or unicode characters and encoding them increases their length significantly.

Is there a better and efficient way to handle this scenario? I need the process to be fast and avoid collisions(a rare one would be okay).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not put the URL in a table and use the primary key as your memcache key?

Comment: I don't need to persist urls. I just need to cache them for a few hours and use the values stored in corresponding Java objects.

Comment: Check if this can help you in URL shortening. https://dzone.com/articles/url-shortener-service-42-lines

Comment: I think creating a url hash would be simpler than what mentioned in the link above.